# Passing char pointers between functions - Are both ways equal? - C

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have done one MCVE code of passing char pointers into other function. I have the dude if both ways of passing char pointer parameter are equal (how `str1` and `str2` are passed into `passingCharPointer1` and `passingCharPointer2` respectably).

Also, I have include comments inside code with the behavior of the free/null functions and their behavior (I would appreciate it if they were also read).

The code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 50

void passingCharPointer1(char *str) {
    strcpy(str, "Hi-1!");
}

void passingCharPointer2(char **str) {
    strcpy(*str, "Hi-2!");
}



int main() {
    // Init char pointers
    char *str1 = malloc((MAX_LENGTH +1)*sizeof(char));
    char *str2 = malloc((MAX_LENGTH +1)*sizeof(char));

    // Gets their values
    printf("Input string 1: ");
    fgets(str1, MAX_LENGTH , stdin);
    printf("Input string 2: ");
    fgets(str2, MAX_LENGTH , stdin);
    printf("\n");

    // Remove '\n' character
    str1[strcspn(str1, "\n")] = '\0';
    str2[strcspn(str2, "\n")] = '\0';

    // Print their values
    printf("BEFORE - Function 1: %s\n", str1);
    printf("BEFORE - Function 2: %s\n", str2);

    // Pass to function in two ways - ARE BOTH WAYS EQUAL?
    passingCharPointer1(str1);
    passingCharPointer2(&str2);

    // Print their values
    printf("AFTER - Function 1: %s\n", str1);
    printf("AFTER - Function 2: %s\n", str2);

    // Freeing pointers
    free(str1);
    free(str2);

    // Print their values after freeing
    printf("\nAFTER FREE 1: %s\n", str1); // Show rare characters (I supposse it is normal behaviour after free)
    printf("AFTER FREE 2: %s\n", str2); // Continue having its content (I supposse it is not normal behaviour after free)

    // Nulling pointers
    str1 = NULL;
    str2 = NULL;

    // Print their values after nulling
    printf("\nAFTER NULL 1: %s\n", str1); // Normal behaviour
    printf("AFTER NULL 2: %s\n", str2); // Normal behaviour

    // Exit success
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Printing `free`-d memory is undefined behavior.

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying by 1 has no effect.  The parameters to the calls to the `malloc()` function are being cluttered b those expressions.  Suggest removing those expressions from the calls to `malloc()`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation worked

Comment: @s7amuser Yes, ok, thank you. But then it is normal that one show content and the other not, right?

Comment: The posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 50.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: @user3629249 The question is if is equal both ways of passing parameters (function1 and function2). Also, thank you for your advice, I will take it in care: always check if is NULL and dont mult *1

Comment: @user3629249 Ok, I will update this. How it was a short MCVE  I supposse it was not needed, but if it clarify code, I will update it

Comment: it is not guaranteed that the heap memory will be undisturbed after the call(s) to `free()` so it is undefined behavior to access the heap memory that the program does not own.

Comment: @JuMoGar Both ways of passing parameters can be used (although the first one is clearer in this case since the function doesn't intend to change the pointer itself). Also, everything is "normal" if undefined.

Comment: regarding: `passingCharPointer2(&str2);`  this is the way to pass a parameter IF the called function is going to change where `str2` points.  Otherwise, the extra `&` just clutters the code

Comment: `s7amuser` and `user3629249` Thank you again both, I will continue studying about this topic then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the functions are not equivalent. The first function accepts pointer by value while the second function accepts pointer by reference. As result the second function can change the original pointer used in an expression as the argument.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void passingCharPointer1( char *s ) 
{
    s = "Bye";
}

void passingCharPointer2( char **s )
{
    *s = "Bye";
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s1 = "Hello";
    char *s2 = "Hello";

    printf( "Before function calls: %s %s\n", s1, s2 );

    passingCharPointer1( s1 );
    passingCharPointer2( &s2 );

    printf( "After function  calls: %s %s\n", s1, s2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Before function calls: Hello Hello
After function  calls: Hello Bye
```

Pay atttention to that accessing memory after it was freed invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your question. Then, for passing a pointer by reference should be with: `&`, isnt it?. Also, if I pass by value (without `&`) and execute `strcpy` also changes value contained inside pointer, as it was passed by reference... why then?

Comment: I mean, passing by value I can modify its content too

Comment: @JuMoGar When the parameter has the type char * it means that the objects (that is characters of the array) are passed by reference and can be changed using the pointer. To change the original pointer itself you have to pass it in turn by reference that is using a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But then, what usefulness can have to pass by reference the pointer (therefore, receive a pointer pointer)? To change the memory address to which it points? or for something else?

Comment: @JuMoGar For example many list functions as for example adding a new node to a list accept the list head by reference because the pointer to head can be changed in the function.

Comment: Ok, I will take it in care. Thank you, again @Vlad from Moscow

Comment: One more thing, I'm sorry for the heaviness. Then, it is recommended pass pointers always by reference, is more powerful, isnt it?

Comment: @JuMoGar You need to pass by reference only if you need to change the original object.

Comment: Then, if I wanna change its content (although I can do it with `strcpy`) I should pass it by reference and do: `*str = "string"`, right?

Comment: @JuMoGar strcpy does not change the pointer itself. It changes characters pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: Oh, ok then, thank you for your help. I will continue  working hard with pointers taking in care your advices.

Answer (score 1):

If you question is truly:

> is equal both ways of passing parameters (function1 and function2)

(and you ignore all of the code in `main()`), then yes, the two functions are essentially equivalent.

The difference is that function1 takes a pointer to a char (which, in the C language, is an idiom for a string) and function2 takes a pointer to a pointer to a char.

But as @Vlad from Moscow points out, function2 allows you to modify the pointer passed into the function.

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you. And what is the adventage of modifying pointer passed? I mean, if I do not pass it with `&`, I can modify its value too, so... Which is the adventaje (or not) of passing pointer with `&`?

Comment: > Which is the adventaje (or not) of passing pointer...  That's simple: if you don't need to modify the pointer, use function1 -- it saves a tiny bit of computation, but more importantly, makes your intent clear.